# POST method api custom end point having unnecessary mandatory ID field

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, symfony4, api-platform.com

I have this custom API endpoint call "register". I had added into "ItemOperations" of the User Entity with the declaration of "POST". When I check back to api platform UI, I saw that there is unnecessary ID field is being mandatory to key in as shown in the screenshot attached.

[image: api for register]

This is my User Entity codes that I have tried

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={"get","post"},
 *     itemOperations={
 *     "get",
 *     "put",
 *      "register"={
 *         "method"="POST",
 *         "path"="/register",
 *         "controller"=User::class,
 *     }
 *     },
 *     normalizationContext={
 *                  "groups"={"user:read"},"swagger_definition_name"="Read"
 *      },
 *     denormalizationContext={
 *                  "groups"={"user:write"},"swagger_definition_name"="Write"
 *      },
 *     shortName="User"
 *
 * )
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"})
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"contact"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     * @Assert\Email()
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Groups({"user:write"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @var string provide in YYYY-MM-DD (neglect Time)
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $dob;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=8,
     *     max=8,
     *     maxMessage="contact number must have 8 character",
     *     minMessage="contact number must have 8 character"
     * )
     */
    private $contact;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $lastName): self
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDob(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dob;
    }

    public function setDob(\DateTimeInterface $dob): self
    {
        $this->dob = $dob;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setAddress(string $address): self
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContact(): ?string
    {
        return $this->contact;
    }

    public function setContact(string $contact): self
    {
        $this->contact = $contact;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And this is my AuthController

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller;
    use App\Entity\User;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
    class AuthController extends AbstractController
    {

        /**
         * @param Request $request
         * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder
         * @param EntityManagerInterface $entity_manager
         *
         * @return JsonResponse
         * @throws \Exception
         */
        public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder, EntityManagerInterface $entity_manager)
        {
            try{
                $contentType = $request->getContentType();
                $content     = $request->getContent();
                $response = new JsonResponse();

                if ($contentType != 'json' || !$content) {
                    $response -> setContent(json_encode(['fail' => 'empty content type or content type is not json format']));
                    $response ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST,'Bad Request');
                }else{
                    $data = json_decode($content, true);

                    $email      = $data['email'];
                    $hasUser    = $entity_manager->getRepository(User::class)->findByEmail($email);

                    if($hasUser){
                        $response -> setContent(json_encode(['fail' => 'user already registered']));
                        $response ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST,'Bad Request');
                        return $response;
                    }


                    //Update User
                    $user = new User();
                    $user ->setEmail($data['email']);
                    $user ->setFirstName($data['firstName']);
                    $user->setLastName($data['lastName']);
                    $user->setDob(new \DateTime($data['dob']));
                    $user->setAddress($data['address']);
                    $user->setContact($data['contact']);
                    $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($user,
                        $data['password']
                    ));
                    $entity_manager->persist($user);
                    $entity_manager->flush();


                    $response -> setContent(json_encode(['success' => 'user successfully added']));
                    $response -> setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_CREATED,'Created');
                }
                return $response;
            }catch (Exception $e){
                //TODO: Log Error
                $response -> setContent(json_encode(['fail' => 'Internal Server Error']));
                $response ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,'Bad Request');
            }
        }

    }
```

I wanted to remove the "Id" mandatory field when I post register. Is there any way that I can do? I am stuck this problem for almost two days. Sorry if I miss out something since I am quite new to API platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the POST Action in Collection Operations, ItemOperation are for getting, updating or deleting your resource, thats why the id is mandatory.

And point your Action to the controller, not the Entity

```
@ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *       "get",
 *       "post",
 *       "register"={
 *         "method"="POST",
 *         "path"="/register",
 *         "controller"= AuthController::class,
 *     }
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *     "get",
 *     "put",
 *     },
 *     normalizationContext={
 *                  "groups"={"user:read"},"swagger_definition_name"="Read"
 *      },
 *     denormalizationContext={
 *                  "groups"={"user:write"},"swagger_definition_name"="Write"
 *      },
 *     shortName="User"
 *  * )
```

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks again Mario. You continuously saving me.